# ¿Cómo podría comparar un array con una variable?

Tags: javascript, array

Holaa, estoy intentando hacer un comprobador que consiste esencialmente en dos cosas:

1. Un array de urls.
2. Una variable que ejecuta la acción de obtener de donde viene el usuario. 
   La cosa es que con lo que he hecho no funciona por lo que sea. 
    
   Dejo aquí el códidgo.

   ```
     <script>
    var doblas = document.referrer;
    console.log(doblas);
    const bad_sites = [

    "https://google.com","https://twitter.com/","https://ionos.es/", "https://www.facebook.com/",

    ];

    if (doblas === bad_sites[]) {

            location.href ='https://www.wyylde.com';

   }
   else{


    console.log('anty');
   }




    </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar algo así:

```
  <script>
 var doblas = document.referrer;
 console.log(doblas);
 const bad_sites = [
  "https://google.com","https://twitter.com/","https://ionos.es/", 
  "https://www.facebook.com/"    
 ];     
  if (bad_sites.includes(doblas)) {    
         location.href ='https://www.wyylde.com';  
 }
else{
 console.log('anty');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y funciona de lujo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro mucho, a las órdenes!